# Is this problem solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, math

**Upd: Now I have a `O(n^3)` algo.**

I'm trying to come up with a reasonable algorithm for this problem:

There are some pairs:

```
(1,2),(1,3),...,(1,n),  
(2,3),(2,4),...,(2,n),  
...  
(n-2,n-1),(n-2,n),  
(n-1,n)
```

And there are m conditions(m >= n), each like that `at most one of [pair a, pair b, pair c, ...] can be selected.` Each condition includes some pairs(maybe 1,2,3,...). And each pair is included in **exactly one** condition.

Now can we find a plan to select n pairs, satisfy that all numbers from 1 to n are included in **exactly 2** pairs?

Only need to judge if it is possible.

For example, when n = 4 and the conditions are `[{(1,2),(2,3)},{(1,3)},{(1,4),(2,4)},{(3,4)}]`, select `(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,4)` is ok.

If it is NP-hard, can we find an algorithm which time complexity is lower than 2^(n^2/4)?

Unfortunately now I only have an algo that enumerate all possible situations. It's worst time complexity is `2^(n^2/4)`.

Nocite that time complexity like `n^m` is not polynomial.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** thoughts, ideas, insights, tries.

Comment: Now I can only use brute force algo. It sounds like k-SAT problem. qwq

Comment: It seems that the solution must pick one pair from each condition. I don't see this specified... is this a requirement? What else is the role of the conditions?

Comment: Can this problem be rewritten to *There are (n²+n)/2 - 1 items and people. Each person has a list of acceptable items and will buy exactly one item. Is it possible for every person to leave satisfied?*

Comment: @trincot  _It seems that the solution must pick one pair from each condition._  **It's false.** Because we may have more than n conditions so sometimes you can pick nothing from one condition

Comment: So is then the rule is that **at most** one pair can be selected from a condition?

Comment: @trincot Right.

Comment: I didn't find this in the question. Can you update the question and add this rule?

Comment: @trincot I've updated it now. thx

Comment: @Daniel I think we can't rewrite the problem like this. :(

Comment: Consider asking this question at [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution not found yet. But there is a combinatorial point of view which is worth mentioning.

Consider your pairs are vertices of a graph. Also, add  `n` vertices labeled `1, ... , n`.

Add undirected edges between a vertex `i` (`i` in `[1..n]`) and all vertices corresponding to pairs that contain `i`.

For each condition, paint all vertices in the condition with a different color. In the end, you will have painted all vertices of the graph (except the vertices labeled `1, ..., n`) and each vertex will have exactly one color.

Your problem can be translated into selecting at most one vertex of each color such that the graph induced by the selected vertices and the vertices `1,...,n` is such that each of the vertices `1,...,n` has degree exactly `2`.

A solution for your example is illustrated in the image below (the induced graph is with blue edges):

[image]

Notice that a solution for the general version of the problem is always a simple cycle of length `2*n` of the form `p(1)--v(1)--p(2)--v(2)--...--p(n)--v(n)--p(1)` such that the colors of `v(1), ..., v(n)` are all different and `p(1), ..., p(n)` is a permutation of `1,..., n`.

Comment: However, did you notice that c >= n? c and n are both variables. I don't think it's a good answer.

Comment: @Error_Yuan Oh, didn't notice this constraint. Sorry. But I think there are better time complexity solutions that can be found in an easier way using the formulation I showed. This was just the brute force. I need to think more.

Comment: I agree with the graph construction, but n^(2*C + 1) is definitely not polynomial in n (unless C is bounded from above by a constant, but that would make the problem trivially insoluble since the solution must contain only C pairs, but all n numbers need to be covered).

Comment: @Stef True. C is actually a function of n. I will remove the mention to the brute force solution, since it's useless. But I will let the graph formulation in the hope that it inspires someone to find a better time complexity.

Comment: @JohnDoe What we know is that the constraints form a partition of the set of pairs (because each pairs belongs to exactly one constraint); since the number of pairs is at most n(n-1)/2, we know that C <= n(n-1)/2. And since the solution will contain at most C pairs and must cover every number from 1 to n exactly twice, we also know that C >= n. Thus n <= C <= n(n-1)/2. And it looks like those two bounds are tight: the exact value of C can be anything between these two bounds.

Comment: @Stef Indeed. That brute force is pretty worse than the brute force the OP already found. I removed it from my answer and let just the graph formulation with the illustration.

Comment: Just noticed the solution must induce a cycle of length `2*n` in the graph I showed. Something like `1--v(1)--2-v(2)--3--...--v(n-1)--n--v(n)--1` where `v(1), ..., v(n-1), v(n)` have different colors. Maybe searching for this kind of cycles can help

Comment: @JohnDoe I have already found an algo which solves the problem in `O(n^3)`! Consider the **flow**.

Comment: @Error_Yuan Cool ! Could you describe it more, please ? I feel like there is a simple `O(n^2)` solution by doing a BFS starting from one of the vertices `1, ..., n` in the graph I mentioned and searching for the cycle of length 2n that visits each color once.

Comment: @Error_Yuan I updated my answer with a mention to this solution. Seems correct to me. Please, let me know if you find a problem with it.

Comment: @JohnDoe How can I find such a circle by bfs?

Comment: @Error_Yuan You start from vertex 1. Every time you see a neighbor, if it's a vertex not in {1,...,n}, you verify in O(1) if its color was already seen. If yes, ignore it. If no, continue the BFS from it. If it's a vertex in {1, ..., n} and it's already visited, verify in O(1) if the cycle has length 2*n. If yes, you have a solution.

Comment: @JohnDoe  Seems it isn't BFS... If it is BFS, how do you verify if a vertex's color is seen? I think it more like DFS... but if it is DFS, its time complexity is not O(n^2) because some vertexs have more than one in-degree.

Comment: @Error_Yuan Keep an array with size equal to the number of different colors. Use this array to check in O(1) if a color was already seen during the BFS. Also, keep the size of the path and the parent for each visited node in the BFS

Comment: @JohnDoe hmm...but in this way some vertexs may be visited twice or more, so I don't think it's O(n^2), in fact, we have n^2 vertexs.

Comment: @Error_Yuan You never visit a vertex twice or more. It's a common BFS in a graph with O(n^2) vertices and O(n^2) edges. The only difference is that you ignore vertices with colors already seen. Time complexity for BFS is O(V+E). So, you stay O(n^2)

Comment: @JohnDoe ...look at your example above. If you start from vertex 1, than you will visit vertex (3,4) at depth 3, with the path: 1->(1,4)->4->(3,4), then how can you find your colored circle without visiting (3,4) any more?

Comment: @Error_Yuan True :/ I think there is no way to recognize that cycle with a simple BFS. Maybe with more than one BFS it's possible, by finding new pieces of the cycle at each new BFS. But then it would be worse than O(n^2).

Comment: @Error_Yuan Could you give more details about your `O(n^3)` algo, please ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Consider a network flow. first set a Source Point(S) and a Target Point(T), then for all the conditions create an edge from S to the condition, with cap 1. Also, for all the numbers i from 1 to n, create an edge from i to T, with cap 2. And for all the pairs, create an edge from the condition the pair is included in to the pair and two edges from the pair to a & b (the pair is `(a,b)`), with cap 1. Then we can use Dinic Algo to find the max-flow in the network. If it is 2 * n, there is such a plan, otherwise, there isn't. We can prove that the worst time complexity is O(n^2 sqrt(n))

Comment: @JohnDoe Anyway, thanks for your graph formulation! This really inspired me!

Comment: @Error_Yuan Sorry, I don't get why the complexity is O(n^2 sqrt(n)) . Isn't it a network with O(n^2) vertices and O(n^2) edges ? Dinic runs in O(E * V^2). Would't it be `O(n^5)` time complexity ?

Comment: @Error_Yuan Anyway , your solution is brilliant ! I believe it works. Thanks for sharing, it's always a pleasure to discuss interesting algorithmic problems with the fellow programmers.

Comment: @Error_Yuan Oh, I see now, it's a special case since the capacities are all 1 or 2. Cool !

Comment: @JohnDoe Right. It is like unit network.